# Unable to revoke user permissions for an Azure application

Tags: azure

I have an application registered in Azure which asks for user consent via oauth2 to read the user's calendar. I am trying to figure out how the user will go about revoking this permission. I believe this is done via myapps.microsoft.com. I do find my application listed here but when I click on it I get this error:

> something went wrong...  You cannot access this application because it
>   has been misconfigured. Contact your IT department and include the
>   following information:  Undefined Sign-On URL for application "xxxxx"

In Azure App Registrations (legacy) there is an option for sign on URL but my application doesn't show up in search results on this screen. In Azure App registrations, the Sign On URL option seems to have been removed. Can someone guide me on how the user will remove consent in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a Home Page URL under Branding in Azure App registrations, you'll at get rid of that particular error when browsing to your app in myapps.microsoft.com.  Then, if the user has consented themselves, you'll be able to Remove the app permission when logged in to myapps.microsoft.com as them.  However, if the app was consented by Admin, the user will not see the choice to remove the app permission.

[Here's a linky](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/aad/revoking-consent-azure-active-directory-applications/) with a better description with pictures.